# Give EC2 instance temporary S3 permission without changing instance profile

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I have a Lambda function to `SendCommand` from an SSM Document to an EC2 instance whenever the instance changes its state to `running`. The Document basically downloads a package from an S3 bucket from another account and installs it on the instance. The bucket policy allows everyone to `List*` and `Get*`.

The issue is that I'm not allowed to modify the instance profile to give it S3 permission. So the question is how do I get this specific package on the instance without changing the instance profile? Is there a different approach to this?

Bucket policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy111",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "NoDelete",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:DeleteBucket",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket_name>"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt111",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:List*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket_name>",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "aws:PrincipalOrgID": "o-111"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "list",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:List*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket_name>/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "aws:PrincipalOrgID": "o-111"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1111",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:Get*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket_name>",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "aws:PrincipalOrgID": "o-111"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "get",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:Get*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket_name>/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "aws:PrincipalOrgID": "o-111"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

SSM Document

```
"inputs": {
  "runCommand": [
    "aws s3 cp {{S3Path}} .",
    "sudo yum install {{PackageName}} -y"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Why does the bucket policy not suffice? Is this a cross-account bucket access?

Comment: I added the bucket policy. It is cross-account. If I run the SSM document on an EC2 instance that doesn't have S3 permission, I get this `fatal error: An error occurred (403) when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden`. If I add S3 permission to that instance profile, it runs fine.

Comment: If it were same-account the bucket policy would suffice, for cross-account it however does not unfortunately. I see no way other than to modify the document, at it makes sense that the policy needs to be updated because you basically want the instance to do things it is simply not allowed to do. A workaround for this specific case would be to copy the object into a bucket in the same account as the instance, update *that* bucket policy and let the command interact with that local bucket.

Comment: What about creating a presigned link to the S3 package and when the EC2 boots it loads the link from SSM, download the package and done?